# CUPS Troubleshooting:"Unable to locate printer "BrotherPrinter"."

Tags: cups

## GOAL \ QUESTION

The goal is to print the CUPS test page by overcoming the error message:

> "Unable to locate printer "BrotherPrinter"."

What tests can be confirmed the root cause of the error message?
Is there a ping-like test that can be performed from cups to confirm that it can "see" the printer on the network?

## BACKGROUND

**Sreenshot of error message provided at bottom of posting**

CUPS was installed on Raspbian Buster (OSMC) on a Raspberry Pi 3B+
The Raspberry pi is NOT wired to the printer via USB

### Install / Setup CUPS

```
sudo apt install cups
sudo usermod -a -G lpadmin osmc
sudo cupsctl --remote-any
sudo systemctl restart cups
```

## OBSERVATIONS

### getent test results

osmc@osmc:~$ `getent hosts BrotherPrinter`
returns nothing

osmc@osmc:~$ `getent hosts BrotherPrinter.local`
returns:

192.168.8.101   BrotherPrinter.local

A Brother HL2280DW is configured into CUPS.  CUPS returns:

Current Connection:  lpd://BrotherPrinter/BINARY_P1

### BrotherPrinter.local ping returns are good:

```
ping BrotherPrinter.local
PING BrotherPrinter.local (192.168.8.101): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.8.101: seq=0 ttl=255 time=3.895 ms
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

CUPS indicates it's unable to locate "BrotherPrinter" but the `ping` command is able to get a response from "BrotherPrinter.local".

So, perhaps "BrotherPrinter" and "BrotherPrinter.local" are considered to be two different things?

---

### Test 1: hostname resolution

Test with the following two commands:

```
getent hosts BrotherPrinter
getent hosts BrotherPrinter.local
```

If you get different answers, then the problem is in hostname resolution.

You could fix this by changing the printer connection URL of CUPS to `lpd://BrotherPrinter.local/BINARY_P1`.

Alternatively, if you want all programs on your system to attempt resolving all hostnames with no domain part using mDNS, you could add `mdns4` to the end of the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

(`getent hosts` tests hostname resolution by doing exactly the same thing as regular programs are configured to do, which may or may not involve connecting a DNS server. Commands like `nslookup` or `dig` are specifically DNS testing tools, which will explicitly contact a DNS server.)

`.local` is a special domain suffix that is reserved for mDNS (multicast DNS) use. If the `hosts:` line in your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file includes `mdns_minimal` or `mdns4_minimal` but not `mdns` or `mdns4`, then mDNS is used to resolve hostnames only when the `.local` suffix is used. Names without the `.local` suffix are queried from a regular DNS server.

And if you ask your router's or your Internet Service Provider's regular DNS server, it's most likely going to come back with authoritative data, telling you that there is definitely no such domain as `.local` in the global Internet - because the `.local` domain names are supposed to be resolved using multicast-DNS in your local network segment, not by contacting any public DNS servers.

---

### Test 2: lpd:// connectivity

If both names `BrotherPrinter` and `BrotherPrinter.local` resolve to the same correct IP address (192.168.8.101 according to your `ping` command), then the problem is somewhere else. The next step is to test connectivity for the actual printing protocol you have chosen to use. Here, you've configured CUPS using a `lpd://` type connection URL, which means CUPS will be trying to connect to the printer using TCP port #515.

You could test this with any program that can make a TCP connection to a specified port, and indicate whether a basic TCP connection was successfully established or not. Commands like `telnet` or netcat (`nc`) are frequently used for such testing.

To eliminate the extra variable of hostname resolution, you could first test using the printer's IP address:

```
telnet 192.168.8.101 515
```

or

```
nc -v 192.168.8.101 515
```

If the `telnet` command reports "Connection established" or `nc` says something like "Connection to 192.168.8.101 port 515 (tcp) succeeded!", you'll know that the printer is responding when connected to the LPD protocol's TCP port. Both of these commands would then stay connected to the printer until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to disconnect.

If the command exits immediately with an error message like `Connection refused`, then the printer is not accepting LPD protocol connections. Perhaps it does not support that printing protocol, or support has been disabled in the printer's configuration.

If the command hangs for a while, and finally exits with a `Connection timed out` error message, then the most common reason is that there is a firewall blocking  TCP packets from your system to the printer, or TCP response packets from the printer to your system, or both. (Firewalls don't generally bother sending the error response that causes the connection to terminate immediately with the `Connection refused` error message: they just stop the packets and let the connection time out.)

Comment: In my case, I was getting this error as a result of an upgrade (fc35) that for some reason DELETED my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file (!). Restoring an old version of it immediately got everything working (no need to restart services or anything). That was an incredibly frustrating experience.